# htk installation problem on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation

I have already download and unpack htk-3.4.1, then according to the htk installation guide I change the directory to this file then type "./configure --prefix=/usr/local/bin.linux" command. it work fine and provide me two necessary commands to install the tool; these are:
1. make all to build htk and 
2. make install to install htk, however when I enter the first command it displays this error

(cd HTKLib && make HTKLib.a) \
      || case "" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/htk/HTKLib'
gcc  -ansi -D_SVID_SOURCE -DOSS_AUDIO -D'ARCH="i686"' -Wall -Wno-switch -g -O2 -I. -DPHNALG   -c -o HGraf.o HGraf.c
HGraf.c:73:77: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <X11/Xlib.h>      /* the X11 stuff makes string.h also available */
                                                                             ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [HGraf.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory`/tmp/htk/HTKLib'
make: *** [HTKLib/HTKLib.a] Error 1

please help me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem installing HTK on Ubuntu 14.04. I found the answer on Voxforge forum. The setup was designed for 32-bit computers, and to install you need to call a 32 bash. Type this on a terminal window:

```
linux32 bash
```

Then proceed with the installation:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/yourname/htk
make all
sudo make install
```

You may also need to install 'libx11-devel', before typing these:

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-devel
```

http://www.voxforge.org/home/dev/acousticmodels/linux/create/htkjulius/tutorial/download

Comment: The correct package name is `libx11-dev`.